# Combining two functions of Integer->String type

Tags: haskell

I have a function called **list_apple**, when given a number 5, it prints 5 "apple" line by line 
using putStr(list_apple 5). i.e:

```
list_apple :: Integer -> String
list_apple k = concat["apple\n" | x <- [1..k]]
```

**results:**

```
apple
apple
apple
apple
apple
```

Another function I have called **a_row_of_apple**, given a number 5

```
a_row_of_apple :: Integer -> String
a_row_of_apple k = concat["apple " | x <- [1..k]]
```

**results:**

```
apple apple apple apple apple
```

---

**Aim:**  I am trying to define a function called list_all_apple, using the two functions above

```
list_all_apple :: Integer-> String
```

results:

```
apple
apple apple 
apple apple apple 
apple apple apple apple
apple apple apple apple apple
```

**My attempt:**
Using a list comprehension

```
list_all_apple :: Integer -> String
list_all_apple k = list_apple k ++ a_row_of_aaple k| x<-[1..k]
```

but did not work. I thought about using zip function. However, the zip takes two lists, and I have two strings.

Comment: “However, the zip takes two lists, and I have two strings.”: To clear that: Strings **are** lists, lists of characters.

Comment: @TimWolla Yes, you are right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this:

```
list_all_apple k = concat [(a_row_of_apple $ x - 1) ++ list_apple 1 | x <- [1..k]]
```

Of course, since `list_apple 1` just evaluates to `"apple\n"`, you could also equivalently write:

```
list_all_apple k = concat [(a_row_of_apple $ x - 1) ++ "apple\n" | x <- [1..k]]
```

which could be further reduced to @wonce's solution of:

```
list_all_apple k = concat [a_row_of_apple x ++ "\n"| x<-[1..k]]
```

(because `(a_row_of_apple $ x - 1) ++ "apple\n"` = `a_row_of_apple x`)

In order words, I don't think you could really get a use of combining `list_apple` productively into this function because the spaces between the words `"apple"` on each line:

```
apple
apple apple
apple apple apple
apple apple apple apple
apple apple apple apple apple
```

must come *before* each newline (`\n`).

---

You could also get rid of `concat` by leveraging the fact that you are already using a list comprehension:

```
list_all_apple k = [s | x<-[1..k], s <- a_row_of_apple x ++ "\n"]
```

or you could just use `unlines` and not have to add the newline character `"\n"` or use `concat`:

```
list_all_apple k = unlines [a_row_of_apple x | x<-[1..k]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Though not using *list_apple* this would be a solution:

```
list_all_apple :: Integer -> String
list_all_apple k = concat[a_row_of_apple x ++ "\n"| x<-[1..k]]
```

Comment: or simply, `unlines [a_row_of_apple x| x<-[1..k]]`. @cold_ice: there is a function called `replicate` which you should look into ...